# IFrame callback, server response not appearing on client

Tags: wcf, http, upload

thanks for clicking.

I am trying to get status feedback using an IFrame for file uploads. I am not trying to get progress or percentages - 
just when a file is done uploading and if it was a success or failure.

THE PROBLEM is that I can't seem to get the server response 
to appear on the client. I have to following design:

I have an iframe on my page:

```
 <iframe id="target_frame" src="" style="border:0px; width:0px; height:0px"></iframe>
```

The form tag points to it:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm" name="fileUploadForm" action="picupload.aspx" method="post" target="target_frame">
```

And the submit button starts a file upload via the iframe:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="upload" />
```

In the picupload.aspx.cs file, I have a method that returns
dynamic data. I then send it to the client:

```
message = data;
Response.Write(String.Format("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.parent.handleResponse('{0}');</script>", message));
```

On the client, I have a response handler:

```
 function handleResponse(msg) {
        document.getElementById('statusDiv').innerHTML = msg;
  }
```

My intent is to see the msg value change for each uploaded file but I never see anything appear in statusDiv, let alone dynamically changing messages.

Can somebody please help??

Comment: I think your code has gone missing

Comment: Thanks Justin. I forgot to click the "code" button. You should be able to see everything now :)

Comment: Can you get any sort of javascript to execute in the frame after an upload finished?  Something as simple as `alert(1);`?

Answer (score 1):

I've been unable to find a way to detect an `iframe`'s server response, but it looks like the purpose of your `iframe` is just to show the results of the form submission request without a page refresh. If so, then maybe you can replace the `iframe` with an [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHR) call.

I'd recommend using some flavor of [Ajax library](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) for simplicity, but I've had a few scenarios where that wasn't an option for one reason or another. Here's a toy example of how to make an XHR form submission request using Javascript without AJAX.

**NOTE:** This example assumes the `form` is not sending file data (that's a whole other kettle of fish, and much better handled with AJAX). It also won't submit the values of `<select>` or `<textarea>` tags, but you could certainly extend the javascript to handle those.

```
/* HTML */
<form action="script.php" method="post"   // these are up to you
    onsubmit="sendFormRequest(this); return false;">

/* Javascript */
function sendFormRequest(form){
    var fields = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var data = [];
    for(var i=0; i<fields.length; ++i){
        if(fields[i].getAttribute('type') != 'submit')
            data[i] = escape(fields[i].name) + '=' + escape(fields[i].value);
    }
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open(form.getAttribute('method'), form.getAttribute('action'), false);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.send(data.join('&'));
    return {'status':req.status, 'responseBody':req.responseText};
}

/* Returns */
Object { status=200, responseBody="<!DOCTYPE html PUB ... \n</body>\n</html>\n" }
```

I doubt this post is still relevant, I'm mainly replying to it because it comes up in search results and doesn't seem to have a quick, usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Until you provide more code, I can only guess at the issue.  I would first check to make sure that the iframe page (picupload.aspx.cs) is host on the same domain as the page that contains the iframe.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Yep, same domain. I just realized i needed to add the "code" wrapper so people could view my code. Let me know if you want to see something else...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

http://www.nbsp.es/2007/11/23/up-libreria-para-subir-archivos-de-forma-oculta/

Help is in spanish, but the code is there.